update values in .cnf from .csv
I have the following .cnf
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress            =

[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress            =

[client]
countryName     = 
stateOrProvinceName = 
localityName        = 
organizationName    = 
emailAddress            =
commonName      = 

Here's the csv headers:
userPrincipalName,displayName,surname,mail,givenName
I need to update the emailAddress and commonName value only under [client] section using the .csv file containing UPN and displayName.
I also need to loop values from csv and update one by so giving me the chance to run another script in between to generate a certificate.
I'm not familiar with bash scripting at all, just starting to learn while building a project.
example:
foreach $upn in $csv {

 update [client].emailAddress = $upn
 run_cert_creation_script_here
}

I'm trying:
sed -i "s/emailAddress.*/emailAddress=$upn/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
but this will update all matching field in the cnf.
Update:
I was able to write this:
#!/bin/bash

# Define the CSV and CNF file paths
CSV_FILE="exportUsers_2024-8-8.csv"
CNF_FILE="clientX.cnf"

# Read the CSV file line by line
while IFS=',' read -r userPrincipalName displayName _ _
do

        echo "UPN: $userPrincipalName"
        echo "Name: $displayName"
        sudo sed -i "52 s/emailAddress.*/emailAddress            = $userPrincipalName/" "$CNF_FILE" 
        sudo sed -i "53 s/commonName.*/commonName              = ""\"$displayName\"/" "$CNF_FILE" 

done < "$CSV_FILE"


[edit] your question to include a sample CSV you want to use the values from to update your CNF file. Without that we have only have half of the sample input and that's not adequate to demonstrate your requirements nor copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Posting a line of headers from a CSV is not the same as posting data from a CSV. Please read [ask] and in particular the part about creating a [mcve].

Reading the CSV 1 line at a time in a shell loop and calling sed multiple times inside the loop would be an extremely inefficient and fragile approach, I highly recommend you don't do that (but I don't know what to tell you TO do instead since you haven't provided a [mcve] yet).

you can just fill UPN and DisplayName in a , sperated CSV. The headings should give a clear idea of the values inside. There nothing fancy going on in the CSV here.

Either you can provide input/output to test with so we KNOW what you want, or everyone trying to help you has to do it and guess at what you want. You stand a better chance of getting help if you do it. See [ask], look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples, and then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] so as many people as possible will be willing/able to help you.

It sounds like what you want to do won't be difficult and can be done in a single call to awk or some other tool, but there are details you haven't shown us yet such as whether or not the CSV fields are enclosed in quotes, what characters the fields you want might contain (some of which can break various types of substitution), etc. I would never consider using sed for something like this as it has no function for handling literal strings but maybe you know something about your input that makes it OK in this case. Until we see a [mcve] with truly representative values, we're guessing.

As a simple example - a & is a valid character in an email address. If your CSV contains one in a upn field then sed "s/email=.*/email=$upn/" will corrupt your data. Similarly for various other characters. So just don't do that and do something like awk '... sub(/email=.*/,""){print "email=" upn}' instead - that's a literal string operation so it'll work no matter which characters are in the upn field of your CSV. And you certainly don't need a slow, fragile shell read loop for this based on what you've shown us so far, nor do you need to have hard-coded line numbers in your script.

Use this regex:
sed -i "/^\[client\]/,/^\[/ s/^emailAddress.*/emailAddress=$upn/" "$CONFIG_FILE"

The first part /^\[client\]/,/^\[/ searches for the portion of the file between [client] and the next section (which starts with a [ ) and then s/^emailAddress.*/emailAddress=$upn/ searches for the string emailAddress within the section and replaces it.

I'm adding the comment here because I can't add comments to the questions yet.  To give you an extra hand, I would need to know how .cnf files are identified (with an ID inside the csv that identifies the file name?) and how the csv is made.  Furthermore, in the example sed that you put in the update, I advise you against statically writing the line to be modified.  Suppose a file is different because there is an extra line, the script would not work.

The cnf will never change. It'll be a bigger problem if it does for some unknown reason and then our certs will also not work. I understand line number based edits are bad but in this example it'll do just fine.
CSV and CNF files are in the same directory assigned to a variable at the start of the script.
